Proving equivalence of Riemann integrability with respect to monotonic function and product integrability
Problem Statement
Let $\alpha$ increase monotonically on $[a, b]$ with $\alpha' \in \mathcal{R}[a, b]$. Let $f$ be a bounded real-valued function. I need to prove:
$$f \in \mathcal{R}[a, b, \alpha] \iff f\alpha' \in \mathcal{R}[a, b]$$
Furthermore, $$\int_a^b f(x) \ d\alpha = \int_a^b f(x)\alpha'(x) \ dx.$$
What I Understand
I've managed to prove the forward direction ($\implies$). Here's my proof:
Let $f \in \mathcal{R}[a, b, \alpha]$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Suppose $M = \sup f$. Then, $\exists$ partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that:
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{P_1} \left(\sup f - \inf f\right) \Delta \alpha &< \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\\
    \sum_{P_2} \left(\sup \alpha' - \inf \alpha'\right) \Delta x &< \frac{\varepsilon}{2|M| + 1}
\end{align*}
Let $P = P_1 \cup P_2$. Observe that since $\alpha' \geq 0$ it holds that $\sup f\alpha' \leq \sup f \sup \alpha'$ and $\inf f\alpha' \geq \inf f \inf \alpha'$. Then,
\begin{align*}
    \sup f\alpha' - \inf f\alpha' &\leq \sup f(\sup \alpha' - \inf \alpha') + \inf \alpha' (\sup f - \inf f)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{P_1 \cup P_2} \left(\sup f\alpha' - \inf f\alpha'\right) \Delta x &\leq \sum_{P_1 \cup P_2} \left(\sup f(\sup \alpha' - \inf \alpha') + \inf \alpha' (\sup f - \inf f)\right) \Delta x\\
    &\leq \sum_{P_1 \cup P_2} \sup f(\sup \alpha' - \inf \alpha')\Delta x + \sum_{P_1 \cup P_2} \inf \alpha' (\sup f - \inf f) \Delta x\\
    &\leq \sum_{P_2} \sup f(\sup \alpha' - \inf \alpha')\Delta x + \sum_{P_1} \inf \alpha' (\sup f - \inf f) \Delta x\\
    &\leq \frac{M\varepsilon}{2|M| + 1} + \sum_{P_1} \inf \alpha' (\sup f - \inf f) \Delta x
\end{align*}
From the mean value theorem, $\Delta \alpha = \Delta x \alpha' \implies \Delta x \inf \alpha' \leq \Delta \alpha$. Then, $$\sum_{P_1} \inf \alpha' (\sup f - \inf f) \Delta x \leq \sum_{P_1} (\sup f - \inf f) \Delta \alpha < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{P_1 \cup P_2} \left(\sup f\alpha' - \inf f\alpha'\right) \Delta x &< \frac{M\varepsilon}{2|M| + 1} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon \implies f \alpha' \in \mathcal{R}[a, b].
\end{align*}
Where I'm Stuck
For the converse ($\impliedby$), I start with $f\alpha' \in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ and given $\varepsilon > 0$, I know there exists a partition $P$ such that:
$\sum_P (\sup f\alpha' - \inf f\alpha')\Delta x < \varepsilon$
I can use MVT to get that for each subinterval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$:
$\Delta \alpha = \alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i-1}) = \alpha'(c_i)\Delta x$ for some $c_i$
But I'm stuck on how to relate:

The Riemann sum of $f\alpha'$ with respect to $dx$
The Riemann sum of $f$ with respect to $d\alpha$

to show that if $f\alpha'$ is Riemann integrable, then $f$ is Riemann integrable with respect to $\alpha$.
Any help would be appreciated!

Use Riemann sums and show that a Riemann sum $\sum f(t_i) (\alpha (x_i) - \alpha(x_{i-1}))$ can be written as $\sum f(t_i) \alpha'(t'i) (x_i-x{i-1}) $ and its difference from Riemann sum $\sum f(t_i) \alpha'(t_i) (x_i-x_{i-1})$ can be made arbitrarily small.

I am sorry, but not sure what u mean. Can you elaborate more? Also, what is $t_i'$ in the argument of $\alpha'$ in the Riemann sum?

$t_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$ is a tag point for the Riemann sum and $t'i\in(x{i-1},x_i)$ is a point based on mean value theorem applied to $\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i-1})$.
